# SSH error when using putty to access MaaS nodes

Tags: 14.04, server, ssh, maas

Essentially I can not log into the nodes provisioned with MaaS via putty or teraterm without first providing an RSA key from the MaaS server.  Juju works just fine as it resides on the host server...  Typically keys are exchanged during the transfer however it seems to be denying public keys.

```
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.10.2' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts. Permission denied (publickey).
```

As such I have two questions. First I'm not sure where to begin so, I'm not exactly sure how to ask... However what I would like to do is take make the server accept these putty and teraterm sessions by default without having to provide a key.

I've searched around a bit but the word SSH on Google brings up 1000 things that are not related.

As far as a RTFM response, I'm not particularly opposed to that so long as its the correct manual and a genuine response.

The second question has not been verified yet so I cannot say for sure if the issue will persist.  However I will verify this a bit later and update the post.  My MaaS configuration seems to be off if it is doing this in the first place.  How can I prevent future nodes from having this issue?

I greatly appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to check whether the MAAS has been taken out of both the machines using the command

```
~/.juju/environments/maas.jenv
```

After doing the above try to use the SSH. It helps to connect.

Comment: that file doesn't seem to be an executable.  Although I did take a look at the contents.  One thing that I can mention right away is that the MaaS controller is included in the setup as well as the nodes.  

There are two authorized keys available for the nodes one seems to be owned by root@MaaS-server and one seems to be owned by juju-client-key.  

does this mean that this is a normal occurrence and these nodes can only be directly accessed by the MaaS controller and or the juju-client? Would I have to add other keys for say a Windows PC with PuTTY?